# Add control into table from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, controls, code-behind

I'm trying to dynamically add asp.net controls into HTML table, not the ASP.NET table.
Well, let's just say that controls that i want to add is a textbox.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: Please provide what you currently have in your aspx page(Page which is havin Table).

Comment: it's been solved. thanks for asking though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing, use `<asp:Panel>` or `<asp:PlaceHolder>` in side any td in which you want to put your dynamic control. and then using their ID you can put your control in side that table.
e.g

Asp File:-

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder1" runat="server"/><td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Code Behind:-

```
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
t1.ID="txt1";
placeHolder1.Controls.Add(t1);
```

Try this and let me know if this works or not.

Comment: Ohk. If it worked for you. Then please don't forget to mark it as answer.